# Where to post Javaplex questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Javaplex (https://github.com/appliedtopology/javaplex ) is a software package for use in computing persistent homology in topological data analysis.  Would questions for use with software like this belong on stackexchange proper (since it's about a computer program),  or on math.stackexchange,  since the whole program is for computing things in math,  or somewhere else?

Answer (score 6):

Questions related to mathematical software and programming can be on-topic on this site if they are to a relevant part mathematical questions. The mere fact that the questions arises in relation to solving mathematical problems does not make the question itself mathematical.

I assume by "stackexchange proper" you mean Stack Overflow. That site is for question on programming; if your question is a question on programming it may be on-topic there. In the past a few questions on it were posted there and [two out of three I could find received an answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javaplex).

Other SE sites you could consider are [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), possibly the best choice, and maybe the statistics site [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Check, will give computational science a try.  The math part is simple, I just want to change the metric it uses from euclidean to a custom metric, so it really is just about the code